# Dual datepicker calendars with autofocus and min date

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using 2 jquery datepickers, one for depart and one for return.

I want the 2nd one to auto open and have the min date set to the value selected in the first calendar + 1 day (i.e. first calendar date was May 21st, 2nd calendar should have the min date set to May 22nd).

As of right now I can get it auto filling the default date of the 2nd calendar to the date selected in the first one.

```
$( "#dep_date" ).datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', numberOfMonths: 3, minDate: +2, onSelect: function(dateText, inst){$("#ret_date").val(dateText);}});
$( "#ret_date" ).datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', numberOfMonths: 3});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
$("#dep_date").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    numberOfMonths: 3,
    minDate: +2,
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        var date = $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', dateText);
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);

        var $ret_date = $("#ret_date");

        $ret_date.datepicker("option", "minDate", date);            
        $ret_date.datepicker("setDate", date);

        $(this).datepicker("hide");

        $ret_date.datepicker("show");
    }
});

$("#ret_date").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    numberOfMonths: 3
});
```

Details:

- Uses the [`setDate`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#method-setDate) method on `datepicker`
- Sets the [`minDate`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-minDate) option on `datepicker`
- Calls the [`show`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#method-show) method on the next `datepicker`

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/4tay7/

Comment: Yup, that worked perfect.  I was trying $ret_date.datepicker("minDate", date) and it wasn't taking, so I guess I needed option.  Plus I was trying to use focus focus events.

Comment: @dawgbone: Glad to help! Please accept the answer if it worked for you.

Comment: done! One thing I did notice was that if have `$ret_date.datepicker("setDate", date);` before `$ret_date.datepicker("option", "minDate", date);` and you select a future date (i.e. a month down the road) and then change it to a date earlier than your first selection (say next week), the 2nd calendar won't default to the new date because it's using the minDate from your first selection. So just change the order to `$ret_date.datepicker("option", "minDate", date); $ret_date.datepicker("setDate", date);` and it works fine.